# python pandas reshaping a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns: `id1` and `id2`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1': list('ABCBAC'), 'id2': [12,13,12,11,13,13]})
print(df)

id1     id2
A       123
B       13
C       12
B       11
A       13
C       132
```

And I want to reshape it (using, groupby, or pivot maybe?) to obtain the following:

```
id1      id2-1    id2-2
A        123       13
B        13        11
C        12        132
```

Note that there are exactly two rows for each `id1` but a great number of different values of `id2` (so I'd rather not do one-hot vector encoding).

There is a preference if the output could be sorted by lexicographic order, to give this:

```
id1      id2-1    id2-2
A        13       123
B        11       13
C        12       132
```

i.e. for each row the values in `id2-1` and `id2-2` are sorted (see the row corresponding to `id1 == 'B'`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***plan***

- we want to create an index that for each successive time we see the values in `'id1'`.  For this we will `groupby('id1')` then use `cumcount()` to give us that new index.
- We then set the index to be a `pd.MultiIndex` with `set_index`
- with the `pd.MultiIndex` we are set up to `unstack`
- finally, we rename the columns with some tricky mapping

---

```
d = df.set_index(['id1', df.groupby('id1').cumcount() + 1]).unstack()
d.columns = d.columns.to_series().map('{0[0]}-{0[1]}'.format)

print(d)

     id2-1  id2-2
id1              
A       12     13
B       13     11
C       12     13
```

Comment: This is the kind of answer that goes into notes for future reference:)

Comment: @A-Za-z too kind

Comment: @A-Za-z Amen.  I agree.

Comment: This is a great answer thank you. Would you also have a way to sort row by row the values in the columns? (faster than an apply should be possible shouldn't it?)

Comment: @ysearka I'm not sure of exactly how you want to sort.  However, whatever it is you are thinking, I'm sure there is a faster way to do it than using `apply`.

Comment: @piRSquared for each row I'd like the value in `id2-2` to be greater than the value in `id2-1`. For instance the second row would be `B 11 13` instead of `B 13 11` (without modifying the other rows).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1': list('ABCBAC'), 'id2': [123,13,12,11,13,132]})
df['id2'] = df['id2'].astype(str)
df = df.groupby(['id1']).agg(lambda x: '-'.join(x))
df['id2-1'] = df['id2'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0]).astype(int)
df['id2-2'] = df['id2'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[1]).astype(int)
df = df.reset_index()[['id1', 'id2-1', 'id2-2']]
```

Comment: I am having a little problem because I over-simplified my sample. My `id1` is filled with numbers, therefore the `groupby.sum()`doesn't act as planned. I've updated my sample.

Comment: See the edit :) Sadly it only works with 2 digit numbers

Comment: Yes, I edited again, my `id2` numbers don't all have the same number of digits (although, I think that could be correcter with a simple `apply`).

Comment: Let's try again, this shouldn't fail :)

Comment: Actually it does, why do you split with `-` since there is none in the data?